# Bash Command line Editing

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have two questions.

Q1. I read a article http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/05/linux-keybindings/comment-page-1/#comment-1750752 in this cntrl+/ works perfectly fine for redoing the last undone edit but Cntrl+? doenot. My system details are

```
[mike@localhost rshare]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.4
Codename:       Tikanga
```

and terminal setting are

```
[mike@localhost rshare]$ stty
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
erase = ^H;
-brkint ixoff -imaxbel
```

Please provide good reference for bash keyboard shortcut.

---

Q2. `$ echo *` prints all the files in the current directory while `$ echo .` simply prints `"."` (without quotes).My question is why it not prints all the files including hidden files in the current directory?

Comment: To print hidden files you need to do `echo .*`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It appears that in this question you are asking multiple, separate questions. The Stack Exchange Question and Answer format works best when each question focuses on a single issue to which an authoritative answer can be given and where the answer can be judged on its technical merits. You don't need to know what the answer is, but one should be possible. I suggest that you [edit] this question to focus on a single issue that can be answered within a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Keybindings

As suggested in that article, `bind -p` lists keybindings.

```
$ bind -p | egrep 'redo|undo'
"\C-x\C-u": undo
"\C-_": undo
# vi-redo (not bound)
```

Note that bash has vi-mode and emacs-mode. Keys behave differently depending on which modes you have selected.

### 2. shell wildcard expansion

`.` isn't a shell wildcard (it is a metacharacter in regular expressions though). Instead I would use

```
echo .*
```

or

```
echo .??*
```

because I'm usually not interested in `.` and `..` and don't have hidden files with tiny names.

[Michael Kjörling](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kjorling) pointed out a superior pattern:

```
echo .[^.]*
```

which is only a couple of characters more to type.

Comment: I often use the shell glob pattern `.[^.]*` which gives me all dotfiles *except* `.` and `..`. (It works by matching the first dot literally, the next character must be anything but a dot which also excludes anything that is not at least two characters including the initial dot, and then any number of characters following that.)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: And here's another one, just because I can, though I'm not sure how portable it is (it works with GNU bash 4.2.37). If you really want *everything* in a single shell glob pattern and can't rely on `shopt dotglob` being set for some reason, then at least in bash `{,.}[^.]*` gives you that. Now we're *really* getting into the interesting parts of shell glob expansion; it works the same as the one I mentioned earlier, really, except `{,.}` expands to *both* the empty string as well as `.`, so you effectively get `[^.]*` (all non-dotfiles) and `.[^.]*` (all dotfiles except `.` and `..`) at once.